# Database "View" using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there an option to create a "View" using Entity Framework programmatically?

Under "View" I mean the following: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out that the requested functionality is not supported using code-first approach at the time:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/827